# Graph algorithm to calculate node degree

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm trying to implement the topological-sort algorithm for a DAG. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) 
First step of this simple algorithm is finding nodes with zero degree, and I cannot find any way to do this without a quadratic algorithm.

My graph implementation is a simple adjacency list and the basic process is to loop through every node and for every node go through each adjacency list so the complexity will be `O(|V| * |V|)`.

The complexity of topological-sort is `O(|V| + |E|)` so i think there must be a way to calculate the degree for all nodes in a linear way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain the indegree of all vertices while removing nodes from the graph and maintain a linked list of zero indegree nodes:

```
indeg[x] = indegree of node x (compute this by going through the adjacency lists)
zero = [ x in nodes | indeg[x] = 0 ]
result = []
while zero != []:
    x = zero.pop()
    result.push(x)
    for y in adj(x):
        indeg[y]--
        if indeg[y] = 0:
            zero.push(y)
```

That said, topological sort using DFS is conceptionally much simpler, IMHO:

```
result = []
visited = {}
dfs(x):
    if x in visited: return
    visited.insert(x)
    for y in adj(x):
        dfs(y)
    result.push(x)
for x in V: dfs(x)
reverse(result)
```

Comment: I think he is asking how to quickly calculate indeg() in your code.

Comment: @linwei: Oh, now I see what you meant by your comment. `indeg(y)` is a variable, not a function. It already has the correct value, we just need to read it. I tried to make that a bit more clear now

Comment: I understood that. It's just that after I read OP' question now I am curious too, how could you initially get all the indeg of every nodes in linear time ?

Comment: @Linwei: Initialize `indeg[x] = 0` for all `x`. For every edge `(v,w)`, increment `indeg[w]`

Comment: One can easily find the indeg at the time of taking input from user . Which would most likely be a loop hence linear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in `o(|v|+|e|)`. Follow below given steps:

1. Create two lists `inDegree`, `outDegree` which maintain count for in coming and out going edges for each node, initialize it to 0.
2. Now traverse through given adjacency list, for `edge (u,v)` in graph g, increase count of `outdegree` for u, and increment count of `indegree` for v.
3. You can traverse through adjacency list in `o(v +e)` , and will have indegree and outdegree for each u in `o(|v|+|e|)`.

Answer (score 0):

The Complexity that you mentioned for visiting adjacency nodes is not quite correct (*O(n<sup>2</sup>)*), because if you think carefully, you will notice that this is more like a BFS search. So, you visit each node and each edge only once. Therefore, the complexity is *O(m+n)*. Where, *n* is the number of nodes and *m* is the edge count.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use DFS for topological sorting. You won't need additional pass to calculate in-degree after processing each node.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/